# React Native grid with grid gap

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make a React Native grid layout and I'm going crazy. First of all, I have this markup:

```
<View style={styles.screen}>
  ...
  <View style={styles.parent}>
    <View style={styles.children}><Text>1</Text></View>
    <View style={styles.children}><Text>2</Text></View>
    <View style={styles.children}><Text>3</Text></View>
    <View style={styles.children}><Text>4</Text></View>
    <View style={styles.children}><Text>5</Text></View>
    <View style={styles.children}><Text>6</Text></View>
    <View style={styles.children}><Text>7</Text></View>
    <View style={styles.children}><Text>8</Text></View>
  </View>
</View>
```

And the styles, I currently have this:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    padding: 10
  },
  parent: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flexWrap: 'wrap'
  },
  children: {
    margin: 5
  }
});
```

The max numbers of columns I want is 3, so this is how it should look like:

[image]

I tried doing some calculus with the Window width, substracting the padding of the main wrapper (screen) but nothing worked.

Comment: Why don't you create 3 individual rows and slice it into 3 with 3 individual columns by using flex ? Is that the part you have an issue with ?

Comment: Yeah, because of the gaps. With CSS I could just make: width: calc((100% / 3) - 20px), with 10px being the gap, so substract 20px (10 to each side) and it would fit perfectly, but I can't do that here

Answer (score 1):

React-Native doesn't support grid layout and flex-gaps, use React-Native FlatList instead

```
import {FlatList} from 'react-native'
...
return (
    <FlatList
        data={you data array here}
        renderItem={({item}) => (
            <View style={styles.children}>
                <Text>8</Text>
            </View>
        )}
        numColumns={3}
    />
)
```

This will render a wrapper to organize your data in a list with three columns

If you are mocking data, I suggest creating an array of fake-data and passing it to FlatList data property

```
const fakeData = new Array(10).fill('hello world')
...
data={fakeData}
```

FlatList has scrolling support of its own, but if you need it, you can turn it off